# VBA global variable value disappear in other sub

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a global variable called flag set up. I can access flag from every module in my code, but when I assign it the value 1 in Sub Command97_Click(), for some reason flag does not keep the value to Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer). When I print the flag in Sub Form_BeforeUpdate it is not equal to 1 anymore. I know that this is silly, but I am new to vba...

Bear in mind my code does more than this, but I am only keeping the basic for my question.

Thanks in advance!

```
Public flag As Integer

Private Sub Command97_Click()
    flag = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If flag = 1 Then
         DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
         MsgBox "Flag = " & flag, vbInformation
         Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put this line after you set `flag = 1` and step through it using debugger/F8: `Form_BeforeUpdate (False)`.  This should take you to the other sub, and the value for `flag` should be 1.  Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a variable scope issue. It depends on where your flag variable is defined, and are there others with the same name elsewhere.
If you say `Public flag as Integer` at the top of a form module, then it's not really global.

[Take a look here for an explanation of scopes.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141693)

Answer (score 0):

Search for "public flag" and "global flag" in all your modules, maybe you have this variable name twice.
It's possible to distinguish between two equally named variables in different standard-modules if you set the module-name before it:

```
Module1.flag = 1
Module2.flag = 1
```

and in form-modules use

```
Me.flag = 1
```

to make sure which flag you use at the moment.